# Move button inside another div

Tags: wordpress, layout, plugins

I am using two different plugins for two button. I want to move one button next to another button. It seems like two button are in two separate divs. So how can i move one button to the div of another button.[image]

Comment: Post your code of what you have done so far so we can help.

Comment: its wordpress with woo commerce. So when i activated the plugin they come up in their respective positions.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you provide us your HTML structure for you both button divs.

Here I assume that, following are the HTML structure for both the buttons:

```
<div class="button1_div"><button>Retail Enquiry</button></div> // html code for button 1
```

And

```
<div class="button2_div"><button>For Product Enquiry</button></div> // html code for button 2
```

As you can see, I have given class to both the divs.

If,my html structure matches with yours, you can add the following jQuery code for that particular page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // condition to check both the divs are exists or not
        if(jQuery('.button1_div').length > 0 && jQuery('.button2_div').length > 0){
            firstButton = jQuery('.button1_div').html();

            jQuery('.button2_div').append(firstButton); // this line will add button at the end of div. So your result will be "For Product Enquiry" and then "Retail Enquiry".
            jQuery('.button2_div').prepend(firstButton); // This lie will add button in beginning of div. So your result will be "Retail Enquiry" and then "For Product Enquiry" buttons.

            jQuery('.button1_div').html(''); // this line will remove <button> from first div, but it will keep empty div
            jQuery('.button1_div').remove(); // this line will remove the first div.

        }
    });
```

You can also use `.insertAfter()` or `.insertBefore()` functions as per where you want to add the button.

Again, if you provide your HTML structure, we can provide you accurate answer.

Please let me know if you need any further help in this.

Thanks!

Comment: i am using wordpress with woo commerce. So i dont know how to do it... Can you please help

Comment: Just post the URL so we can take a look at the source code.